# Can I Debug GWT-RPC procedures run by Tomcat and static content run by Apache Webserver (with IntelliJ)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, gwt, intellij-idea

On my Windows development machine I have IntelliJ setup to run my the static html through Apache Webserver and the GWT-RPC services with Tomcat. Everything is working except the debugging of the server code of the GWT-RPC services. Is it possible to still debug the GWT-RPC server code this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now can debug server code with the described setup:

To be complete I include the steps I already knew and had done:

First you have to configure Tomcat to support remote debugging. This is described in link that Christian Kuetbach gave in his answer. In short it is adding two options to the jvm:

```
-Xdebug

-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=<yourport>,server=y,suspend=n
```

(I already did this step)

The seccond step is where I needed help, configure IntelliJ.

You have to include a Remote Run/Debug configuration. In this configuration you need to specify the port  from step 1. Also, before starting the GWT debugging you have to start this Remote debug configuration so it will connect to the Tomcat debug socket.

Now you can debug the client code and the server code in the same IntelliJ session.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it:

1. Configure tomcat server instance in IntelliJ and make sure you can start your application WITHOUT GWT debugger. In other words in your IntelliJ IDEA go to edit configurations and add tomcat local server and choose your war file to be deployed to tomcat
2. Start your tomcat in debug mode through IntelliJ
3. Make sure you can open your application and it works at the URL you expect it to work, should be something like that `http://localhost:8080/applicationContextThatYouSpecifiedInTomcatDeployentTabConfiguration`
4. Make sure that now you can debug your server side by clicking inside you application and checking if the requests are stopped at appropriate break points on server.
5. Create GWT run configuration in IntelliJ

   - Make sure that you have Dev Mode Parameters set to "-noserver -bindAddress 0.0.0.0" noserver means when you will start GWT configuration from intelliJ it won't start embedded server, since we're using Tomcat as our server now.
6. Run GWT configuration through IntelliJ in debug mode - and YES you have now two configurations running at the same time: one for client side(GWT) debug, another one for server side(Tomcat) debug.
7. Now, in your browser add to the end of URL following text `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:9997`.
   For example if in URL you have `http://localhost:8080/hiThereMyApp/index.html` the new URL should look like `http://localhost:8080/hiThereMyApp/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:9997`

P.S. sometimes browser's gwt plugin will complain that 127.0.1.1 host is not allowed as a GWT codebase, in this case try either replacing `127.0.1.1` to `localhost` or your computer's ip address, or try to configure your browser's GWT plugin to actually allow your desired gwt codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, however the question is about using apache webserver for static gwt client code, and tomcat for the webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understad you correct?

- You have a GWT application running in dev-mode hostet in intelliJ
- And you have the serverpart of this Application running hostet within a tomcat?

If so, you should [start your tomcat with enabled remote-debugging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1) and connect you intelliJ.

Comment: That's right, GWT running in dev mode but on a local webserver (with the -noserver option). I already tried to add the suggested jvm options but IntelliJ is not breaking on the breakpoints.

Comment: So where and how do I setup IntelliJ IDE so it knows how to debug the remote Java code?